# Property Transfer in SOAPUI. How to transfer data with specific parameters?

Tags: web-services, soap, automation, soapui

I have such kind of response:

---

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://.....">
<s:Body>
  <GetHistoricalMeterReadingsByEanResponse xmlns="....">
     <GetHistoricalMeterReadingsByEanResult xmlns:a="....." xmlns:i="http://....">
        <Header xmlns=".....">
           <HasException>false</HasException>
           <Message/>
        </Header>
        <a:HistoricalReadingSet>
           <a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet>
              <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
              <a:HistoricalReadings>
                 <a:HistoricalMeterReading>
                    <a:ClientReadingDate i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
                    <a:EdsnMeterId>3523525</a:EdsnMeterId>
                    <a:EnergyProductType>ELK</a:EnergyProductType>
                    <a:MeterReadingId>1842643</a:MeterReadingId>
                    <a:Mutation>
                       <a:Consumer i:nil="true"/>
                       <a:DossierId i:nil="true"/>
                       <a:Initiator i:nil="true"/>
                       <a:MarketEvent>Historical</a:MarketEvent>
                       <a:MarketEventDate>2015-01-28T00:00:00</a:MarketEventDate>
                    </a:Mutation>
                    <a:NrOfRegisters>2</a:NrOfRegisters>
                    <a:ProcessId i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:ReadingSource>Customer_TMR</a:ReadingSource>
                    <a:RegisterReadings>
                       <a:RegisterReading>
                          <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                          <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                          <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                          <a:TariffType>L</a:TariffType>
                          <a:Value>1345</a:Value>
                       </a:RegisterReading>
                       <a:RegisterReading>
                          <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                          <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                          <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                          <a:TariffType>N</a:TariffType>
                          <a:Value>2345</a:Value>
                       </a:RegisterReading>
                    </a:RegisterReadings>
                    <a:Status>Accepted</a:Status>
                    <a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>false</a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>
                    <a:CanStartDispute>false</a:CanStartDispute>
                    <a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>false</a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>
                 </a:HistoricalMeterReading>
                 <a:HistoricalMeterReading>
                    <a:ClientReadingDate i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
                    <a:EdsnMeterId>3523525</a:EdsnMeterId>
                    <a:EnergyProductType>ELK</a:EnergyProductType>
                    <a:MeterReadingId>1842645</a:MeterReadingId>
                    <a:Mutation>
                       <a:Consumer>8714252018141</a:Consumer>
                       <a:DossierId>23074990</a:DossierId>
                       <a:Initiator>1114252018146</a:Initiator>
                       <a:MarketEvent>Periodic</a:MarketEvent>
                       <a:MarketEventDate>2015-09-14T00:00:00</a:MarketEventDate>
                    </a:Mutation>
                    <a:NrOfRegisters>2</a:NrOfRegisters>
                    <a:ProcessId i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:ReadingSource>Customer_EDSN</a:ReadingSource>
                    <a:RegisterReadings>
                       <a:RegisterReading>
                          <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                          <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                          <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                          <a:TariffType>L</a:TariffType>
                          <a:Value>3000</a:Value>
                       </a:RegisterReading>
                       <a:RegisterReading>
                          <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                          <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                          <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                          <a:TariffType>N</a:TariffType>
                          <a:Value>4000</a:Value>
                       </a:RegisterReading>
                    </a:RegisterReadings>
                    <a:Status>Accepted</a:Status>
                    <a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>false</a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>
                    <a:CanStartDispute>true</a:CanStartDispute>
                    <a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>true</a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>
                 </a:HistoricalMeterReading>                    
              </a:HistoricalReadings>
           </a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet>
        </a:HistoricalReadingSet>
     </GetHistoricalMeterReadingsByEanResult>
  </GetHistoricalMeterReadingsByEanResponse>
```

The problem is: I use this response in oreder to find there an item with 3value field = true. I need such item for the next request method.

I tried smth like this but it didn't work:

```
    <a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading a="http://....">
{
for $x in //a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading
where $x/a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading//a:CanStartDispute/text() = 'true'
return $x
}
</a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading>
```

What is wrong? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xml the numbers are not alloweds as a first character of tag names, besides your xml is not well formed since some tags are not correctly closed. Try first correcting your xml.

```
<a:SetOfItems>   
<a:Item>
 <a:Id>1</a:Id>
 <a:firstValue>12121212</a:firstValue>                    
 <a:secondValue>sdfhjfsdf</a:secondValue>
 <a:thirdValue>false</a:thirdValue>
</a:Item>

<a:Item>
 <a:Id>2</a:Id>
 <a:firstValue>12121212</a:firstValue>                    
 <a:secondValue>sdfhjfsdf</a:secondValue>
 <a:thirdValue>true</a:thirdValue>
</a:Item>
</a:SetOfItems>
```

Then to add your XQuery as a property transfer to select only the `<a:Item>` elements where `<a:thirdValue>` has a text value `true` you can use the follow expression:

```
<a:SetOfItems xmlns:a="blabla">  
{
for $x in //*:Item
where $x/*:thirdValue/text() = 'true'
return $x
}
</a:SetOfItems>
```

Note the use of `*` wildcard to refer any namespace.

Applying this XQuery to your XML you will get:

```
<a:SetOfItems xmlns:a="blabla">
    <a:Item>
        <a:Id>2</a:Id>
        <a:firstValue>12121212</a:firstValue>
        <a:secondValue>sdfhjfsdf</a:secondValue>
        <a:thirdValue>true</a:thirdValue>
    </a:Item>
</a:SetOfItems>
```

**EDIT BASED ON THE QUESTION UPDATE**

I think that there are various things wrong in your XQuery, the follow XQuery works for your xml:

```
<a:HistoricalReadingSet xmlns:a="http://a">
{
for $x in //*:HistoricalReadingSet/*:HistoricalMeterReadingSet
where $x/*:HistoricalReadings/*:HistoricalMeterReading/*:CanStartDispute/text() = 'true'
return $x
}
</a:HistoricalReadingSet>
```

It's generate the follow result:

```
<a:HistoricalReadingSet xmlns:a="http://a">
    <a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet xmlns:a="http://a" xmlns:i="http://i" xmlns="http://b" xmlns:s="http://soap">
        <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
        <a:HistoricalReadings>
            <a:HistoricalMeterReading>
                <a:ClientReadingDate i:nil="true"/>
                <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
                <a:EdsnMeterId>3523525</a:EdsnMeterId>
                <a:EnergyProductType>ELK</a:EnergyProductType>
                <a:MeterReadingId>1842643</a:MeterReadingId>
                <a:Mutation>
                    <a:Consumer i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:DossierId i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:Initiator i:nil="true"/>
                    <a:MarketEvent>Historical</a:MarketEvent>
                    <a:MarketEventDate>2015-01-28T00:00:00</a:MarketEventDate>
                </a:Mutation>
                <a:NrOfRegisters>2</a:NrOfRegisters>
                <a:ProcessId i:nil="true"/>
                <a:ReadingSource>Customer_TMR</a:ReadingSource>
                <a:RegisterReadings>
                    <a:RegisterReading>
                        <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                        <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                        <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                        <a:TariffType>L</a:TariffType>
                        <a:Value>1345</a:Value>
                    </a:RegisterReading>
                    <a:RegisterReading>
                        <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                        <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                        <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                        <a:TariffType>N</a:TariffType>
                        <a:Value>2345</a:Value>
                    </a:RegisterReading>
                </a:RegisterReadings>
                <a:Status>Accepted</a:Status>
                <a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>false</a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>
                <a:CanStartDispute>false</a:CanStartDispute>
                <a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>false</a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>
            </a:HistoricalMeterReading>
            <a:HistoricalMeterReading>
                <a:ClientReadingDate i:nil="true"/>
                <a:EanId>111425200000005564</a:EanId>
                <a:EdsnMeterId>3523525</a:EdsnMeterId>
                <a:EnergyProductType>ELK</a:EnergyProductType>
                <a:MeterReadingId>1842645</a:MeterReadingId>
                <a:Mutation>
                    <a:Consumer>8714252018141</a:Consumer>
                    <a:DossierId>23074990</a:DossierId>
                    <a:Initiator>1114252018146</a:Initiator>
                    <a:MarketEvent>Periodic</a:MarketEvent>
                    <a:MarketEventDate>2015-09-14T00:00:00</a:MarketEventDate>
                </a:Mutation>
                <a:NrOfRegisters>2</a:NrOfRegisters>
                <a:ProcessId i:nil="true"/>
                <a:ReadingSource>Customer_EDSN</a:ReadingSource>
                <a:RegisterReadings>
                    <a:RegisterReading>
                        <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                        <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                        <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                        <a:TariffType>L</a:TariffType>
                        <a:Value>3000</a:Value>
                    </a:RegisterReading>
                    <a:RegisterReading>
                        <a:MeasureUnit>KWH</a:MeasureUnit>
                        <a:MeteringDirection>LVR</a:MeteringDirection>
                        <a:NrOfDigits>6</a:NrOfDigits>
                        <a:TariffType>N</a:TariffType>
                        <a:Value>4000</a:Value>
                    </a:RegisterReading>
                </a:RegisterReadings>
                <a:Status>Accepted</a:Status>
                <a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>false</a:BudgetCanStartSettlement>
                <a:CanStartDispute>true</a:CanStartDispute>
                <a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>true</a:OtherSupplierCanStartSettlement>
            </a:HistoricalMeterReading>
        </a:HistoricalReadings>
    </a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet>
</a:HistoricalReadingSet>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

If you only want to take the `<MeterReadingId>` value where `<CanStartDispute>` sibling is true, you can simply use the follow XPath instead of XQuery:

`//*:HistoricalReadingSet/*:HistoricalMeterReadingSet/*:HistoricalReadings/*:HistoricalMeterReading/*:MeterReadingId[../*:CanStartDispute/text() = 'true']`

Hope it helps,

Comment: Ok, I might made some errors in naming the tags.. I tried to show what kind of request I have. Do you have any idea about whether my code is on the right way or not? Thank you

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova I update the XQuery check it out `:)`

Comment: thanks for help but it did not resolve the issue, I always get error java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova soapui throws this exception when something is wrong in the xquery you can see more info in soapui error log which is located in SOAPUI_HOME\bin. Anyway the sample I show you works correctly... if you want share the exact XML and the XQuery to check what could be wrong.

Comment: I added logs. Seems like it is some error which they haven't fixed in last version - 5.2.1 :( I will try to reverst version or wait till they fix it

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova it's strange I tried also with `5.2.1` version and it's working for me...

Comment: I actually have a longer path to the Item tag and I specify all the tags to get it like in xpath and I make it in start and end tags and also to get to thirdValue.. for example:
<a:parenttag1//a:parenttag2//a:parenttag3//a:parenttag4 xmlns:a="blabla"> etc.. 
and also in where statement:
where $x/a:parenttag1//a:parenttag2//a:parenttag3//a:parenttag4//a:thirdValue/text() = 'true'

Maybe this is wrong?

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova it's possible that the problem comes from here... please edit the question to add your exactly XML and the XQuery this way I could try with your exact sample and tell you what is going on `:)`

Comment: here is my test code:

`<a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Nuts.Consumption.Model.Contract">
{
for $x in //a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading
where $x/a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading//a:CanStartDispute/text() = 'true'
return $x
}
</a:HistoricalReadingSet//a:HistoricalMeterReadingSet//a:HistoricalReadings//a:HistoricalMeterReading>`

Comment: I edited the post, it is more convinient to look at the code, thank you very much for trying to help!

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova your XQuery has some things wrong, I update my answer, hope this time it fits your requierements `:)`

Comment: So it finds all the true values, right? and returns that part of xml which has these true values? And what if I need the Id of the Item which has CanStartDispute = true, so basing on the example, how can I just get 1842645 (MeterReadingId of second item) because it has CanStartDispute = true and I need it then for the next method call, only the id number?

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova in this case why you don't simply use a xpath? take a look at my updated response `:)`

Comment: Hey, it works!:) Thank you a lot. I did not know about such construction in groovy like you specified I am new in this sphere but thank you! You helped me a lot

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova at last works, nice to help you `:)`

Comment: Hi, could you recommend some tutorial to solve issues like I have? because it seems I have a lot of more questions :)

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova there are a lot of good resources for this, but you can start reading the XPath tutorial in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath `:)`. You can also make some tries with for example: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html